# How to autorun wpa_supplicant on Debian startup

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, wpa-supplicant

I'd like to run `wpa_supplicant -D wext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` on Debian startup (runlevels 2-5). I found some vague instructions from a related question that said to put a script in `/etc/init.d/` and then symlink to it from the apropriate `/etc/rcRUNLEVEL.d/` directories. However, I noticed that there are already some files named "wpasupplicant" that probably run at startup:

> /etc/network/if-down.d/wpasupplicant
>
> /etc/network/if-post-down.d/wpasupplicant
>
> /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
>
> /etc/network/if-up.d/wpasupplicant

They all are symlinks to the same script, `/etc/wpa_supplicant/ifupdown.sh`. It has a comment at the beginning saying it "[...] allows ifup(8), and ifdown(8) to manage wpa_supplicant(8) and wpa_cli(8) processes running in daemon mode." However, the closest it gets to calling `wpa_supplicant` itself is (in functions.sh):

```
WPA_SUP_BIN="/sbin/wpa_supplicant"
[snip]
start-stop-daemon --start --oknodo $DAEMON_VERBOSITY \
    --name $WPA_SUP_PNAME --startas $WPA_SUP_BIN --pidfile $WPA_SUP_PIDFILE \
    -- $WPA_SUP_OPTIONS $WPA_SUP_CONF
[snip]
start-stop-daemon --stop --oknodo $DAEMON_VERBOSITY \
    --exec $WPA_SUP_BIN --pidfile $WPA_SUP_PIDFILE
```

Does that mean it's safe to make an init.d script for `wpa_supplicant`, and if so what would it look like?

**General info:**

- Debian Squeeze (5.0)
- official wpasupplicant package (v0.6.10-2.1)

The full contents of my system's `functions.sh` and `ifupdown.sh` are here (dependent, of course, on my system's uptime—it's a five-year-old laptop that greatly enjoys overheating):

[functions.sh](http://thetrees.tk/functions.sh)

[ifupdown.sh](http://thetrees.tk/ifupdown.sh)

Answer (score 7):

If your goal is to get your wireless interface configured on startup (vs. putting the `wpa_supplicant` command in a script for other reasons), you can use `/etc/network/interfaces` and the ordinary config file `wpa_passphrase` generates to achieve this result.

In `/etc/network/interfaces` (assuming `wlan0` is your wireless interface and the config from `wpa_passphrase` is in `/root/your-wpa.conf`):

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-conf /root/your-wpa.conf
```

On my system I have a tab (not spaces) at the start of the "wpa-conf" line. Had trouble entering a tab for the web when typing this response. Not sure if that matters.

I did not need to edit or do anything to the WPA conf file. It is what I get from the command

```
wpa_passphrase myssid mysecret >wpa.conf
```

See [How to use a WiFi interface](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse) on Debian.org and `/usr/share/doc/wpasupplicant/README.wpa_supplicant.conf.gz` locally.

I tested this on Jessie and no longer have any Squeeze systems left - but I imagine you have upgraded in the 4 years since asking the question.

Answer (score -1):

Edit the wpa_supplicant.conf file and add it to /etc/network/interfaces

http://wiki.debian.org/WPA#Why.3F